# Using threading in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to build a GUI that can control a robot arm to move to a certain coordinate. The idea is that, when the coordinate has been passed into a function for the arm to calculate and move. I would also like to have another thread "E - Stop" that also runs in parallel. When I hit the "E - Stop" button, it will intercept the moving function and send a set of commands that will the robot to stop.

I tried to have a print statement in the console to check if the e stop is running in background, but it only print once and when I tried to hit the e stop button, nothing works. It works in a script but not in a GUI class

Below is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from Reach_Kinematics import Kinematics
import threading
import keyboard
class Reach_Sim_GUI_Class:
    def __init__(self, Reach_Kinematics: Kinematics):
     
        self.comport = "COM6"
        self.flag = False
        self.coordinates = []
        self.kin = Reach_Kinematics  
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Reach Simulation GUI")
        self.root.geometry("400x400")
        self.setup_gui()
        self.run_thread()
        self.root.mainloop()
   
    
       


    def setup_gui(self):
        # Create labels for the coordinate input fields
        x_label = ttk.Label(self.root, text="X (in meters):")
        y_label = ttk.Label(self.root, text="Y (in meters):")
        z_label = ttk.Label(self.root, text="Z (in meters):")
        #range_label = ttk.Label(self.root,text="Range 0.4 meters")
        # Create entry fields for coordinates
        self.x_entry = ttk.Entry(self.root)
        self.y_entry = ttk.Entry(self.root)
        self.z_entry = ttk.Entry(self.root)

        # Create a button to add coordinates
        add_button = ttk.Button(self.root, text="Add Coordinate", command=self.add_coordinate)

        # Create a label above the listbox
        coordinates_label = ttk.Label(self.root, text="Coordinates:")

        # Create a listbox to display coordinates
        self.coordinates_listbox = tk.Listbox(self.root)
        
        # Create a home button 
        self.home_button = ttk.Button(self.root, text="Home", command=self.home)

         # Create a "Run" button
        self.run_button = ttk.Button(self.root, text="Run", command=self.move_kin)

        # Create a "Stop" button
        self.stop_button= ttk.Button(self.root, text="E - Stop", command=self.e_stop)

        # Place widgets in the GUI
        #range_label.pack()
        x_label.pack()
        self.x_entry.pack()
        y_label.pack()
        self.y_entry.pack()
        z_label.pack()
        self.z_entry.pack()
        add_button.pack()
        coordinates_label.pack()
        self.coordinates_listbox.pack()
        self.home_button.pack()
        self.run_button.pack()
        self.stop_button.pack()


    def add_coordinate(self):
        x = self.x_entry.get()
        y = self.y_entry.get()
        z = self.z_entry.get()
        
        try:
            self.coordinates.append([float(x), float(y), float(z)])
            self.coordinates_listbox.insert(tk.END, f"({x}, {y}, {z})")
            self.x_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.y_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.z_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showinfo("INVALID COORDINATES!","Please re-enter coordinates")
            self.x_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.y_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.z_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

    # def submit_coordinates(self):
    #     self.placecoordinates = self.coordinates
    
    def home(self):
        self.kin.move_arm_to_pos([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.5207, 0.0])

    def move_kin(self):
        for coord in self.coordinates:
            coord = [coord]
            self.kin.CalculateandMove(coord)

    def run_thread(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.move_kin)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.e_stop)
        t1.start
        t2.start
    
 

    def e_stop(self):
        print("E Stop Running")
        self.stop_button.configure(command=threading.Thread(target=self.e_stop))
        if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
            self.kin.stop_arm_movement()
            self.kin.send_disable_comms()
            self.kin.stop_flag = True

  
    def delete_coordinates(self):
        self.coordinates_listbox.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.coordinates = []
        messagebox.showinfo("Complete", "Coordinates input is complete.")
        self.flag = False
```

I tried having the button's command as a thread, also have another function that activates the thread and pass them into **init** but nothing works..

Comment: Note that `t1.start` will not start the thread.  It should be `t1.start()` instead.  Same for `t2`.

Comment: Instead of using keyboard to check for inputs you can use tkinters [`.bind`](https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) method and instead of threading you could use tkinters [`.after`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/) method